# How to trigger a trigger

Tags: vb.net, xaml, triggers

My question relates to how to initiate as action based on user mouse input.

I have a wpf window that displays information on an organization.  Some organizations are vendors in which case vendor information is displayed in another row of the grid.  I use the following trigger to display/hide that row.  This works as desired.

```
<RowDefinition>
   <RowDefinition.Style>
      <Style
         TargetType="RowDefinition">
         <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsVendor}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Height" Value="*" />
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </RowDefinition.Style>
</RowDefinition>
```

For an organization which is not a vendor, the user can click on a button that adds vendor information and links that new information to the organization.  However, that action does not cause the trigger to fire.  Is there a way to do that?  Or is there a different approach that would work better?

Comment: Make sure you raise a `PropertyChanged` event for `IsVendor` after changing the state.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I will use a converter and bind the value of Height property.

```
<RowDefinition>
   <RowDefinition.Style>
      <Style TargetType="RowDefinition">
         <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding IsVendor, Converter={StaticResource IsVendorConverter}}" />
      </Style>
   </RowDefinition.Style>
</RowDefinition>
```

The converter will receive your boolean value (IsVendor) and returns "0" if IsVendor is false and "*" if IsVendor is true.

```
public class IsVendorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var isVendor = (bool)value;
            if (isVendor)
            {
                return "*";
            }
            return "0";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

You didn't share your xaml, but here is a sample used with a button (clicking one button changes the height of the other one).

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:IsVendorConverter x:Key="IsVendorConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Width="200" Height="{Binding IsVendor, Converter={StaticResource IsVendorConverter}}" />
        <Button Width="200" Height="100" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
        private bool _isVendor = false;
        public bool IsVendor { 
            get { return _isVendor; } 
            set { _isVendor = value; OnPropertyRaised("IsVendor"); } 
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyRaised(string propertyname)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsVendor = true;
        }
    }
```